# Why this array throws an array out of bound exception

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

When I call this function from timer why this try throw the array our of bound exception.

How can I solve this query. This code is called in between the run function. `list<Address> addresses` is go out of bound array exception. Tell me some way to solve this query

```
public String get_address(double latitude ,double longitude)
{
    String address = null;

    if(Geocoder.isPresent())
    {
        try{
            Geocoder geocoder2 = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
              List<Address> addresses;
              addresses = geocoder2.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 2);
               if(addresses != null) {
                     Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);

                     StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
                     for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                     strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                     /*if(returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0){
                         strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(0) + ", ");
                       }

                       strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getLocality() + ", ");
                       strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getCountryName());
                     */

                     address=strReturnedAddress.toString();
                     }
                     else{
                     address="No Address returned!";
                     }
               //return address;

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("MyAPP", "Reverse geo lookup failed", e);
                address="reverse geo look up failed";
             //return address;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        address="Geocoder is not present";
        //return address;
    }
    return address;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`addresses` can be empty(so different from null but you can't get the first item)

replace `if(addresses != null)` by `if(addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty())`

Comment: now it show address="No Address returned!"; how to get address perfectly tell me solution to get an address

Comment: well it depends on the latitude and longitude you give to the function.I suppose the Geocoder didn't return something for every Geolocation point in the world.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

> returns a list of Address objects. Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available.

So is returning a new ArrayList with 0 objects. you need to check with:

```
if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
```

Comment: thank for ur reply ....this code is working properly sepratlly when i put this code in timer run methode it generate a this else mode now it show address="No Address returned!"; how to get address perfectly tell me solution to get an address

Comment: Can you tell us what are the longitude and latitude you are trying to get Address? Is possible that this coordinate doest not have any address associated

Comment: hey there is one problem location manager can not return latitude and longitude ...but when i did this program sepratelly for only geo locator its return all the values......when i put this code in timer then it shows this problem not getting latitude and longitude....

Answer (score 0):

Since adresses list is initialized, it's possible that is empty, but not null.

```
if(addresses != null && !adresses.isEmpty())
```

Comment: thank u for u reply now it show address="No Address returned!"; how to get address perfectly tell me solution to get an address